# Overlay slide in and out from right to left

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an overlay that slides in from right to left upon clicking the "Open" text on the page. This overlay currently covers the whole page.

The class name is Overlay and the contents of the overlay is under .overlay-content

I would like the overlay to cover exactly half of the page.

I've attached the code listed below.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.left = "50%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.left = "100%";
}
```

```css
.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 50%;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover,
.overlay a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {
    font-size: 20px
  }
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}


/*#text{
 position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}*/

.text-block {}

.text-block p {
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
}

.button {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

#button {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#button a {
  background: #999;
  padding: 1em 2.4em;
  font-size: .9em;
  margin: 1em;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<htmL>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <span style="float:right;" onclick="openNav()">&#8641;open</span>
  <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <div class="overlay-content">
      <div class="text-block">
        <h1>"Fever" T-shirt</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      </div>
      <button class="button">Purchase</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="button"><a href="#">Button 1</a></div>

</body>

</htmL>
```

Here is the image of what i would like to achieve.
[Expectedoverlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vI3Lj.jpg)
Actual result
[Overlaywholewidth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvYUI.png)
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: in openNav function change `0%` to `50%` , and in `.overlay` style change width  to `50%`

Comment: Thanks @Mohamed-Yousef ! The overlay does slide half of the page. However, the close button is not visible as a result. Can you help with how to display the close button? Thanks again

Comment: the changes to `50%` doesn't affect the close button at all

Comment: if you read my comment again I said *in .overlay style change width to 50%*

Comment: Thanks for answering my questions! Everything is working as expected.  I'm new to this space and appreciate your patience.

Comment: never mind Raj .. you're totally welcome .. Have a great day :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you wanted...

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.left = "50%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.left = "100%";
}
```

```css
.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover,
.overlay a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {
    font-size: 20px
  }
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}


/*#text{
 position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}*/

.text-block {}

.text-block p {
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
}

.button {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

#button {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#button a {
  background: #999;
  padding: 1em 2.4em;
  font-size: .9em;
  margin: 1em;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<htmL>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <span style="float:right;" onclick="openNav()">&#8641;open</span>
  <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <div class="overlay-content">
      <div class="text-block">
        <h1>"Fever" T-shirt</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      </div>
      <button class="button">Purchase</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="button"><a href="#">Button 1</a></div>

</body>

</htmL>
```